# Magnetic field of a living human

Tags: electromagnetism, home-experiment, biophysics

Is it true that a human body is like a bar magnet? Say our head is north pole while the legs are south pole, or vice versa? If so, can we confirm it by experiment say with the 360 Pro compass etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the characteristics of the magnetic field surrounding a human brain?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11470/)

Comment: The short answer: No. No. Yes, you can confirm it is not true.